# Swift how to sort tableview by distance

Tags: ios, swift

Hi I'm looking for an elegant way to sort an array of objects by distance in Swift and cocoa.

I have a web service that returns a list of locations(latitude/longitude) in JSON and I want to sort it based on the distance of user's current location.

any suggestion will be appreciated.

EDIT: Just to clarify, I want to know how and where I can sort the array in a TableViewController since the user's current location will be available after the didUpdateLocations of LocationManager is called.  Probably a newbie question though.

Comment: Is this not more of a geometry question, than a programming question?

Answer (score 3):

```
   var yourarray : [location] = []

   yourarray.sort({ $0.distance > $1.distance })
```

Comment: more realistically you would probably have a func `distance(point1, point2) -> CLLocationDistance` and your closure would look like `{ distance(currentCoordinate, $0.coordinate) > distance(currentCoordinate, $1.coordinate) }`

Comment: Do you have a project that does this in a TableViewController? I'm in a learning process of swift and cocoa and when I pass the current location to a func in viewDidLoad its to early, the location is not assigned yet.

Comment: this link will help you to get location https://github.com/rshankras/WhemAmI 

this link will help you to learn uitableview in swift.
http://makeapppie.com/2014/07/12/swift-swift-how-to-use-uitableview-in-swift/

Answer (score 0):

To work with location objects you have to include the CoreLocation framework to your project.

Then, to compute the distances:

```
import CoreLocation

func someFunc() {
    let location1 = CLLocation(latitude: ..., longitude: ...)
    let location2 = CLLocation(latitude: ..., longitude: ...)

    let distance = location2.distanceFromLocation(location1)

    // do something with the distance
}
```

That's the basics. Hope you get the idea.

Comment: I got this part thanks, the problem for me is how and where I can sort this array in a TableViewController since the user's current location is available only when the didUpdateLocations of LocationManager is called.  I know its probably a newbie question